# "log file not found" in Texmaker with Windows 10 and MikTex

Tags: texmaker, windows

I have two PCs both running on *Windows 10* that I installed on each machine several years ago. One PC is old and very slow, the newer one is much more powerful. I also downloaded and installed *MikTeX* and then *Texmaker* (vers. 5.1.2) on both machines. The machines ran fine for years on any program that I tried, obviously including *Texmaker*.

Since I use the faster machine most of the time, last week I decided to wipe it clean, re-install *Windows* 10 and then *Texmaker*. I downloaded and installed *Windows* 10: no problem. Then I downloaded *Texmaker* (vers. 5.1.3) from the appropriate site and installed it. To my surprise, and disappointment, when, as a quick check, I used the *Texmaker* wizard to create a simple letter and tried to compile it, I got the comment “log file not found”. Puzzled, I decided to run the same simple program on the slower machine. Everything worked fine. I then decided to delete *Texmaker* (vers 5.1.3) from the new machine and re-install the older vers. 5.1.2. on the newer machine, However, I still couldn’t run the program, again getting the comment “log file not found”.

This is beginning to make me think that the problem has nothing to do with *Texmaker*, but is rather a *Windows* problem. I have downloaded and re-installed *MikTeX* twice on the new machine from the correct website, but it makes no difference, I get the same result running *Texmaker*. I then tried downloading and installing TexStudio, but when I tried to run that on the new machine, it told me that *MikTeX* wasn’t installed on the PC! Browsing the Internet for a possible solution, I see that “log file not found” seems to be a fairly frequent problem, but it usually seems to be associated with a Texmaker problem.

I have used *MikTeX* and Texmaker for many years and installed them on several PCs, with no problems. If anybody has a suggestion, I should be extremely pleased to read it. Maybe it would help to check out the PC, but I don’t know of a program to do that.

Comment: Most likely miktex is not installed at the place where texmaker is configured to look but as you have given no information about  either it is hard to help

Comment: Thanks for the comment. How exactly do I tell Texmaker where to look? I never have done so before when I have installed it Texmaker many times with success. I assume that I should tell it to look at: C:\users\hjb\AppData\local\progs\Miktex, which is the automatic location used by MikTeX. Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: I have never used miktex or texmaker but searching this site for texmaker configuration shows lots of examples eg https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477199/configuration-of-texmaker-with-portable-miktex

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look. Incidentally, I am running everything as an administrator. Some people seem to find that that makes a difference.

Comment: is miktex in the path? That means what do you get if you run on a command line `where pdftex`?